# Server Error Error: PDFDownloadLink is a web specific API. You're either using this component on Node, or your bundler is not loading react-pdf f

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have created this Report card generator in Next.js, but trying to test `@react-pdf/renderer` with this simple example before implement it in my project. Yet I'm receiving this error.

`Server Error Error: PDFDownloadLink is a web specific API. You're either using this component on Node, or your bundler is not loading react-pdf from the appropriate web build.`

```
import React from 'react';
// import Report from '@/pages/report/index';
import { PDFDownloadLink, Text, Document, Page } from '@react-pdf/renderer';

const TestComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Document>
      <Page>
        <Text>Hello World</Text>
      </Page>
    </Document>
  );
};

export default function ReportGenerator() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <PDFDownloadLink document={<TestComponent />} fileName="report.pdf">
          Download PDF
        </PDFDownloadLink>
        <TestComponent />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the exact same error, and tried several solutions, but this is the easiest and Nextjs aproved.
Just include the `'use client'` directive in the top of your file.
For more informaton you can check this: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#the-use-client-directive

Answer (score 1):

Next.js is trying to statically render the PDF at build time which doesn't work with PDFDownloadLink since it needs to be handled client side. I was able to resolve this by using hooks to conditionally render it by the client instead of in the static site build.

```
export default function ReportGenerator () {

  const [isClient, setIsClient] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsClient(true)
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <>
      { isClient ?
        <div>
          <PDFDownloadLink document={<TestComponent />} fileName="report.pdf">
            Download PDF
          </PDFDownloadLink>
          <TestComponent />
        </div>
      : null}
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Next dynamic function to manually set server-side rendering off and import it through that function instead of the regular import

```
"use client";

import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const PDFDownloadLink = dynamic(
  () => import("@react-pdf/renderer").then((mod) => mod. PDFDownloadLink),
  {
    ssr: false,
    loading: () => <p>Loading...</p>,
  },
);
```

instead of

```
"use client";

import { PDFDownloadLink } from "@react-pdf/renderer";
```

Answer (score 0):

Whereever you are importing it as, import it as below:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const ReportGenerator = dynamic(() => import("./path_to_your_ReportGenerator"), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

Assumption:

Here `ReportGenerator` has the `PDFDownloadLink` from `@react-pdf/renderer`

*p.s: Change it to your needs accordingly*